# How to declare a pointer to a class object in an unsafe block in C#

Tags: c#, pointers, fixed, unsafe

Can't I declare a pointer variable to my own class object like below?

```
static void Main() {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    unsafe {
        fixed (MyClass* pMyClass = &myClass) {
            /// Do Somthing here with pMyClass..
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do?

Comment: I became to know the keywords unsafe & fixed yesterday and just  studying and testing now. I coudln't find any explanation on class objects. You mean I can't or just don't study it?

Comment: We are just baffled why you should want to do this.

Comment: I know many people don't recommend using 'unsafe' in C# and also  expected responses like this. But I'm studying C# and wanted to know more. I know I may not use pointers for objects in C# forever but hoped to hear more about the potential ability of C# from experts like you guys. I think there's a big difference between "I know but I don't do it" and "I don't know and I don't do it".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This page explains why: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y31yhkeb.aspx

C# does not allow pointers to references:

> A pointer cannot point to a reference or to a struct that contains references, because an object reference can be garbage collected even if a pointer is pointing to it. The garbage collector does not keep track of whether an object is being pointed to by any pointer types.

You could argue that the `fixed` keyword should allow this because it would stop the GC from collecting the object. This may be true, but consider this case:

```
class Foo {
    public SomeOtherComplicatedClassAllocatedSeparatley _bar;
}

unsafe void Test() {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo._bar = GetComplicatedObjectInstanceFromSomePool();

    fixed(Foo* fooPtr = &foo) {
        // what happens to `_bar`?
    }
}
```

The `fixed` keyword cannot overreach into members of whatever has been dereferenced, it has no authority to pin the reference-member `_bar`.

Now arguably it still should be possible to pin an object that does not contain other reference-members (e.g. a simple POCO) and it is possible to pin a `String` instance, but for some reason the C# language designers just decided to prohibit pinning object instances.

Comment: You can pin without using `fixed`.  Instead, you use `GCHandle.Alloc(..., GCHandleType.Pinned)`